# real-time date from server on java?

Tags: java, date, server

how to take the real-time date and time from the server where my jar is deployed on java?

I want to set the creation date of my orders to the date-time when the server received the request, how can I do that in java?

I tried:

```
  Date newDate = new Date();
  Date createdDate = DATE_FORMATTER_SERVER.parse(DATE_FORMATTER_SERVER.format(newDate));
```

Comment: And what is wrong with this approach? --- A remark: instead of [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), I'd suggest corresponding classes from the [`java.time` package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html).

Comment: Be careful with using the term "real-time". That term has a [specific meaning in computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing).

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.Instant.now().toString()
```

## Details

Never use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. These legacy classes are terribly flawed in design. They were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Capture the current moment as seen in UTC, an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Serialize to text using standard format from ISO 8601.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

Parse such strings.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following and adapt it to your needs:

```
 Date remoteDate = null;
 URL url = new URL(REMOTE_SERVER_URL);
 URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
 HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;
 connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
 connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
 connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects( true );
 connection.setRequestProperty( "User-agent", "spider" );
 connection.connect();
 
 Map<String,List<String>> header = connection.getHeaderFields();
 for (String key : header.keySet()) {
     if (key != null && "Date".equals(key)) {
         List<String> data = header.get(key);
         String dateString = data.get(0);
         SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
         remoteDate = sdf.parse(dateString);
         break;
     }
 }
```